# Thingsboard: Updated a telemetry entry via REST API?

Tags: rest, thingsboard

I am curious if someone was able to update a certain telemetry record via REST API?

Is this not supported yet?

Comment: Yeah this is certainly possible. I've done it heaps. You'll need to use the swagger-ui. Go to "https://{YOUR_DOMAIN}/swagger-ui.html". Under telemetry-controller, saveTimeseries, fill in the boxes to do a post. NOTE: To override a telemetry value you will need to have THE EXACT same timestamp value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JacksonB's answer works like a charm.

But the API name has changed to `saveEntityTelemetry` in the latest version.